# How can I add an event listener to delete an Ace Editor instance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ace-editor

This is what I got so far, I am also looking into editor.session.on('change', ); but no luck yet. I appreciate any help  on this. Thank you.

```
var code_editor = ace.edit(id, {
        theme: "ace/theme/tomorrow_night_eighties",
        mode: mode_name,
        maxLines: 30,
        wrap: true,
        autoScrollEditorIntoView: true,
        enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
        enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
    });
    code_editor.addEventListener("keydown", (ev) => {
        const key = ev.key; 
        
        if (key == "Backspace") {
            alert("pressed");
            code_editor.destroy();
            code_editor.container.remove();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you really have to, you should attach the event listener to the editor container witch is a html div element not to the code_editor object it self:

code_editor.addEventListener -> code_editor.container.addEventListener.

and I noteced that some keys, the "Backspace" included, does not fire the "keydown" event and I don't know why.

I found an official demo for [creating keyboard commands](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/demo/keyboard_shortcuts.html) which seems to me the right way to do it.
I recommend you to spend some more time reading the documentation and take a look at their domos too.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help. I will try what you suggested, check out the demo, and update on this problem asap.